# microsecond data.. Loop, 'for every 15 minute interval"

Tags: python, pandas

```html
--------datetime----------------date--------------time--------close
0   2021-04-16 02:45:00.532000  2021-04-16  02:45:00.532000 4155.25
1   2021-04-16 02:45:05.460000  2021-04-16  02:45:05.460000 4155.5
2   2021-04-16 02:45:05.533000  2021-04-16  02:45:05.533000 4155.5
3   2021-04-16 02:45:09.863000  2021-04-16  02:45:09.863000 4155.25
4   2021-04-16 02:45:09.863001  2021-04-16  02:45:09.863001 4155.25
5   2021-04-16 02:45:09.863002  2021-04-16  02:45:09.863002 4155.25
6   2021-04-16 02:45:26.653000  2021-04-16  02:45:26.653000 4155.5
7   2021-04-16 02:45:30.088000  2021-04-16  02:45:30.088000 4155.5
8   2021-04-16 02:45:30.088001  2021-04-16  02:45:30.088001 4155.5
```

i have microsecond data... i want to run my function/script multiple times on my data. I want run a Loop on every 15-min interval the data has. Is there a way I can Loop the data in its current state (microseconds) and gather 15 minutes worth of data so i can run my function against these 15 minutes (and continue to run on new 15 minutes worth of data until there are no other 15 minutes periods available)

i hope that makes sense. I just dont know how i would execute this in Pandas or another python library. need guidance on gathering 15 mins worth of data and the loop structure

Comment: Well, `pandas` does have a `groupby` option that might be able to combine the rows, but if it were me, I'd do it iteratively, row by row.

Comment: thanks, how would you do it iteratively to chunck 15mins worth of data together at a time to run analysis on? i looked at Timeseries analysis of pandas and i see creating points at 15min intervals, not not chunking data at specific lengths of time.

Comment: What sort of analysis do you want to do on the data?

Comment: i need every observation, every row in each 15 minute interval, not a summary or aggregation of the chunked data set

Comment: If you do it iteratively, you're tracking the start of the current interval.  Pseudocode `if this_row_time > interval_start + 15:` / `start new bucket`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this a particularly efficient method but it should filter the data of the data frame to return a set of records for each 15 minute interval.

You can then pass those records to your function and/or do whatever analysis is required.

1. Get first datetime in data.
2. Calculate which 15 minute period the datetime from step 1 belongs to and set that as  the `start_datetime`.
3. Set the `end_startime` to be 15 minutes after `start_datetime`.
4. Data is filtered to return only records for current 15 minute period.
5. If there is any data it's passed to functions/analysed, otherwise the loop ends.
6. `start_datetime` is set to `end_datetime`.
7. Repeat from step 3.

Like I said perhaps not the most efficient method and there are probably better approaches, but it worked for the small (1269 rows) sample of data I created based on the data you posted.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',parse_dates=['datetime'])

first_datetime = min(df['datetime'])
start_min = int(first_datetime.minute/15)*15

start_datetime = datetime(first_datetime.year, first_datetime.month, first_datetime.day, \
                          first_datetime.hour, start_min, 0)

keep_going = True

while keep_going:
    
  end_datetime = start_datetime + timedelta(minutes=15)

  df_15mins = df[(df['datetime']>=start_datetime) & (df['datetime']<end_datetime)]
  
  if df_15mins.empty:
    keep_going = False
  else:
    # do analysis
    print(df_15mins.head(1))
    print(df_15mins.tail(1))
    start_datetime = end_datetime
```

Comment: thanks norie! ive tested it and it repeatedly returns 15 mins worth of my data.  exactly what i was looking for.